# How to remove Unique Indexes without knowing its name

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and I need to remove an index without knowing its name.

I have multiple instances where the `index` was created using `Liquibase` script. I want to drop the indexes created and add a new index.

I have a script that would give me the `Drop` statements.

```
select format('drop index %I.%I;', schemaname, indexname) as qry
from pg_indexes
where schemaname not in ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast') 
and tablename='table_name' 
and indexname!='table_name_pkey'
```

But I am not sure how to use the result set to drop the inedexes.
Executing using `SQL Shell/ Liquibase` where I can add SQL Statements. Cant make long functions to do that.

Comment: How are you executing this query?

Comment: Executing using SQL Shell/ Liquibase where I can add SQL Statements. Cant make long functions to do that.

Comment: [PL/PGSQL can do this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). (Might need a [`DO` block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this with DO block like below:

```
do $$
declare
x text;
begin

x=(select string_agg(format('drop index %I.%I;', schemaname, indexname), ' ') as qry
from pg_indexes
where schemaname not in ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast') 
and tablename='test' 
and indexname!='test_pkey');

execute x;
end $$
```

[DEMO1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=478202be9ade420c96f1f93fc48bfbb9)

Same you can do with function/Procedure(Depend upon your Version of PostgreSQL) like below:

```
create or replace function remove_index(table_name varchar, table_pkey varchar) returns void
as $$
declare
x text;
begin

x=(select string_agg(format('drop index %I.%I;', schemaname, indexname), ' ') as qry
from pg_indexes
where schemaname not in ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast') 
and tablename=table_name
and indexname!=table_pkey);

execute x;

end;

$$
language plpgsql
```

and call above function like below:

```
select * from remove_index('test','test_pkey')
```

[DEMO2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=35f343750da614938842d0965a46359d)